# Is it possible to replace or modify values from projections or anonymous classes?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

In my application I am using [projections](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-projections) to map `*Entity` objects to simplified or modified versions of the actual record in the database.

However, I have a particular use case where I am required to replace a certain value from one of the nested projections. Since these are interfaces and also get proxied by Spring, I am not sure if what I want is actually possible but to bring it down to one very simpel example:

Assume I have a `UserEntity` and a `User` projection. For my `User` projection I can simply execute:

```
User user = this.userEntityRepository.findById(userId);
```

However, if I want to change something, I am not sure if that is possible. Namely, I cannot do something like this:

```
if (user.getAge() < 18) {
  user.setDisplayName(null);
}
```

Now, I am aware that I could create an anonymous class `new User() { .. }` and just pass in the values I required but in my case the objects are nested and hence this is not an option.

### The question

Is there another way to replace a value, e.g. `displayName` as above, without using an anonymous class?

---

### Elaborative example

Reading the following is not really necessary but in order to illustrate my issue in more detail I have pseudo-coded an example that shows a bit closer what the problem is in my particular case.

We have a simple `UserEntity`:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "app_user")
public class UserEntity {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private Long id;

  @Column
  private String firstName;

  @Column 
  private String lastName;

  @Column 
  private Integer age;

  // Setter & Getter ..
}
```

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "event")
public class EventEntity {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private Long id;

  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "event")
  private List<EventAttendeeEntity> attendees;

  // ..
}
```

We have a table which maps users to events:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "attendee")
public class AttendeeEntity {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private Long id;

  @ManyToOne
  private EventEntity event;

  @ManyToOne
  private UserEntity user;


  // ..
}
```

Further, we have projections for these entities which we prepare as views for our clients:

```java
/*
 * Projection for User
 */
public interface User {
  // All the properties ..  
}
```

```java
/*
 * Projection for AttendeeEntity
 */
public interface Attendee {

  Long getId();

  User getUser();

}
```

```java
/*
 * Projection for EventEntity
 */
public interface Event {

  Long getId();

  String getName();

  List<Attendee> getAttendees();

}
```

In one of the services we fetch `UserEvent`. Here, let's say, we want to remove the names of all users below 18 and still return `userEvent` we just fetched.

```java
public Event getEvent(Long id, Boolean anonymize) {

  Event event = this.eventRepository.findById(id);

  // The "anonymize" is to highlight that I cannot 
  // simply solve this in a User-projection
  if (!anonymize) {
    return event;
  }

  event
    .getAttendees();
    .stream()
    .peek(attendee -> {

       User user = attendee.getUser();

       if(user.getAge() < 18) {

         // Here we create a new user object without a name

         User newUser = new User() {
            @Override
            String getDisplayName() { return null; }
            @Override
            Integer getAge() { return user.getAge(); }
         }

         // !! This is where we hit the problem since we cannot
         // !! replace the old user object like this
         attendee.setUser(newUser);
       }        
     });

  return event;
}
```

Comment: I don't think so it is possible. If possible then there is no difference between interface and implementing class

Comment: @Eklavya I'm afraid so. I really start to regret going with projections. Their fine for simple stuff like fetching an entity "_as is_" but when it gets more complicated, they're just not an option. E.g. now I have a list of items and I want to determine which one of those items the user likes. I don't think one can do that with projections.

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to use SPEL in you projection selector. Please try

```
public interface Attendee {

  Long getId();

  @Value("#{target.user.age >= 18 ? target.user : new your.package.UserEntity()}")
  User getUser();

}
```

Replace you.package with the package of UserEntity. Pay attention to put new UserEntity() and not new User(). This way an empty model will be projected as an empty interface User.

Comment: Unfortunately this is not an option in my case. In my actual example I actually need to replace one projected property by another. I realize that this is not quite clear in my question.

Comment: I updated the code accordingly. It should be more clear now why SPEL is not an option.

Comment: Still i confirmed that spel can be used. I've modified my answer after you've updated the code. Please retry now.

Comment: Now it's just an object where everything is `null`. What if I still need the age of `UserEntity`?

Comment: And it's not an option to pass it into the constructor. My actual example is a bit more complex than this. To get closer to my example: Imagine you want to remove the name _and_ set a random age for all users which are younger than 18. That's closer to what my requirements are, I'm afraid.

Comment: you can for example call an utils static method inside your spel expression : @Value("#{your.package.utils.UserUtils.cleanUser(target)}")

Answer (score 0):

You can't use projections to update your code.

> As a final note, it's important to remember that projections and excerpts are meant for the read-only purpose.

[API Data Rest Projections Baeldung](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-rest-projections-excerpts)

Comment: Alink might provide solution to the question here, but it is encouraged to post the answer properly with your own description.